# Ubuntu 18.04 MSFT touchpad

Tags: 18.04, xorg, touchpad

On my last Ubuntu 18.04 installation on my MSI laptop, I had managed to setup my Elan touchpad using `synaptics` and the `synclient` commands.

My current setup is a Lenovo Legion Y540 with Ubuntu 18.04 again. The touchpad can move the cursor, two fingers scroll correctly, the buttons can click, but single or multi-pressing don't. The <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> combination (touchpad deactivation) works. I tried to see if I had a synaptics compatible touchpad, so I ran `xinput --list` and I got:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Microsoft Microsoft® Nano Transceiver v1.0 Mouse  id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Microsoft Microsoft® Nano Transceiver v1.0 Consumer Control   id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Microsoft Microsoft® Nano Transceiver v1.0 Consumer Control   id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ITE Tech. Inc. ITE Device(8910) Consumer Control  id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ MSFT0001:01 04F3:309E Touchpad            id=18   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Microsoft Microsoft® Nano Transceiver v1.0    id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Microsoft Microsoft® Nano Transceiver v1.0 System Control id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated C           id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ITE Tech. Inc. ITE Device(8910) Wireless Radio Control    id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ITE Tech. Inc. ITE Device(8910) Keyboard  id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=19   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Microsoft Microsoft® Nano Transceiver v1.0 Consumer Control   id=20   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Microsoft Microsoft® Nano Transceiver v1.0 Consumer Control   id=21   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ITE Tech. Inc. ITE Device(8910) Consumer Control  id=22   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I tried to install `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` and it prompted me to remove some core packages to go to previous ones (or at least I think), which seems not optimal. Here's the output:

```
sudo aptitude install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  xserver-xorg-core{ab} xserver-xorg-input-synaptics 
0 packages upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 1 414 kB of archives. After unpacking 4 187 kB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 xserver-xorg-core : Conflicts: xserver-xorg-video-modesetting which is a virtual package, provided by:
                                - xserver-xorg-core (2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4.2), but 2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4.3 is to be installed
                                - xserver-xorg-core-hwe-18.04 (2:1.20.4-1ubuntu3~18.04.1), but 2:1.20.4-1ubuntu3~18.04.1 is installed
                                - xserver-xorg-core (2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4.3), but 2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4.3 is to be installed
                                - xserver-xorg-core (2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4), but 2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4.3 is to be installed

 xserver-xorg-core-hwe-18.04 : Conflicts: xserver-xorg-core but 2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4.3 is to be installed
                               Conflicts: xserver-xorg-video-modesetting which is a virtual package, provided by:
                                          - xserver-xorg-core (2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4.2), but 2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4.3 is to be installed
                                          - xserver-xorg-core-hwe-18.04 (2:1.20.4-1ubuntu3~18.04.1), but 2:1.20.4-1ubuntu3~18.04.1 is installed
                                          - xserver-xorg-core (2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4.3), but 2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4.3 is to be installed
                                          - xserver-xorg-core (2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4), but 2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4.3 is to be installed

 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04 : Conflicts: xserver-xorg-core (>= 0~) but 2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4.3 is to be installed
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

      Remove the following packages:                                                                      
1)      xserver-xorg-core-hwe-18.04 [2:1.20.4-1ubuntu3~18.04.1 (bionic-updates, now)]                     
2)      xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04 [1:7.7+19ubuntu8~18.04.2 (bionic-updates, now)]                            
3)      xserver-xorg-input-all-hwe-18.04 [1:7.7+19ubuntu8~18.04.2 (bionic-updates, now)]                  
4)      xserver-xorg-input-libinput-hwe-18.04 [0.28.1-1~18.04.1 (bionic-updates, now)]                    
5)      xserver-xorg-input-wacom-hwe-18.04 [1:0.36.1-0ubuntu1~18.04.1 (bionic-updates, now)]              
6)      xserver-xorg-video-all-hwe-18.04 [1:7.7+19ubuntu8~18.04.2 (bionic-updates, now)]                  
7)      xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu-hwe-18.04 [19.0.1-1~18.04.1 (bionic-updates, now)]                      
8)      xserver-xorg-video-ati-hwe-18.04 [1:19.0.1-0ubuntu1~18.04.1 (bionic-updates, now)]                
9)      xserver-xorg-video-fbdev-hwe-18.04 [1:0.5.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1 (bionic-updates, now)]               
10)     xserver-xorg-video-intel-hwe-18.04 [2:2.99.917+git20171229-1ubuntu1~18.04.1 (bionic-updates, now)]
11)     xserver-xorg-video-nouveau-hwe-18.04 [1:1.0.16-1~18.04.1 (bionic-updates, now)]                   
12)     xserver-xorg-video-qxl-hwe-18.04 [0.1.5-2build2~18.04.1 (bionic-updates, now)]                    
13)     xserver-xorg-video-radeon-hwe-18.04 [1:19.0.1-0ubuntu1~18.04.1 (bionic-updates, now)]             
14)     xserver-xorg-video-vesa-hwe-18.04 [1:2.4.0-1~18.04.1 (bionic-updates, now)]                       
15)     xserver-xorg-video-vmware-hwe-18.04 [1:13.3.0-2build1~18.04.1 (bionic-updates, now)]              

      Install the following packages:                                                                     
16)     xserver-xorg [1:7.7+19ubuntu7.1 (bionic-updates)]                                                 

      Leave the following dependencies unresolved:                                                        
17)     xserver-xorg recommends xserver-xorg-video-all
```

I didn't find anything on the web for that kind of "MSFT[...] Touchpad", as it is neither `Elan` nor `Synaptics`. I would be really glad to be able to, at least, activate single-finger pressing gesture, if not edge scrolling on all edges and other things I could do with `synclient`. Thanks to anyone who can help me do that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are using the HWE kernel, so it asks you to remove the HWE `xserver-xorg` packages and replace them with non-HWE.

Instead, try installing the HWE `synaptics` package:

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-hwe-18.04
```

Restart your computer for the changes to take effect.

If you are wondering what is HWE, you can read [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack).

Comment: That installation went well. The first time, `synclient` returned something like `No synaptics driver found`, and that was what was blocking me, I thought I didn't have a `synclient`-compatible touchpad, and everytime I was confronted to that I was just deleting the `xserver-xorg...` thing. I happened that I rebooted after that one time, and now it's working! It gives me all the parameters I can change. In the end, having an `MSFT` touchpad didn't change anything.

So it was simple in the end, thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help!